# Ionic and Firebase User Authentication, page restriction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have built a simple app that lets you register an account using Firebase Auth and login.

I used Ionics starter "tab" application for this. I followed the tutorial here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers

for preventing routes based on the Auth state of the user. using the code below, i've prevented you from accessing the dashboard tab without being logged in just for testing purposes however, you can still access it. I followed the tutorial step by step and this is what I have.

**app.js**

```
// Before anything else I define firebase, create a reference to the url, 
// create a service for the url and create the Auth function.

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'firebase'])

   .constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://<firebase-name>.firebaseio.com/')

   .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])

   .factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://<firebase-name>.firebaseio.com/");
      return $firebaseAuth(ref);
   }])

   ...
```

**app.js .run()**

```
// Then in my `.run()` function I listen for our state change that fails  
// because it needs to authorized first.

.run(function($rootScope, $state, $ionicPlatform) {

  // ionic init. code here

  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
     // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
     // and redirect the user back to the login page
     if(error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
         $state.go("login");
     }
  });
})
```

**app.js .config()**

```
// Finally in my `.config()` I have my $stateProvider set up and my dashboard
// tab is resolving as to have auth required to view.

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
       url: '/tab',
       abstract: true,
       templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })

    .state('login', {
       url: '/login',
       templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl as ctrl'
    })

    .state('tab.dash', {
       url: '/dash',
       views: {
         'tab-dash': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
            controller: 'DashCtrl'
         }
       },
       resolve : {
         // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
         // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
         currentAuth: ["Auth", function(Auth) {
           // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
           return Auth.$waitForAuth();
         }]
       }
     })

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

regardless of all this, when I click a temporary link on the login page (where the app starts) it still takes me to the dashboard page, even when not logged in!

What am I missing here?

Comment: verify that error is really "AUTH_REQUIRED", e.g. log it to console. if it really is we need to investigate further...

Comment: It doesn't appear it is throwing any error. I did `console.log('StateChangeError: ', error);` and nothing logged.

Comment: no other errors in your console? In the example its `return Auth.$requireAuth();` and you have `return Auth.$waitForAuth();`

Comment: That was the problem. In their home state they have the requireAuth and then further down they have waitForAuth want to put that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you posted it says  In the example you posted on the firebase site it says `return Auth.$requireAuth();` and you have `return Auth.$waitForAuth();`